# Footer showcasing unusual behaviour

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a static web page as a part of a bigger project (the project is in Laravel).
Everything seems to work fine except for the footer that is behaving unusually.
Despite being at the bottom of the HTML tree, it tends to occupy much more space, overlapping many of the elements above it.

I have already tried changing the div (footer) to the 'footer' element and then to a 'section' element but to no avail.

My HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Medical Insurance</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('web/css/medicalInsuranceStyles.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- header -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3">
                <a href="https://www.letsmd.com/">
                    <img id='main-logo' src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/images/logo-without-Tagline.svg')); ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- banner -->

        <div id='banner-container'>
            <div id="transparent-div"></div>
            <div id='banner-text-div'>
                <h1>Smart Health Insurance Cover</h1>
                <h2>Starting from ₹5/day</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- content part one -->

        <div>
            <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id="content-div-one">
                <h2>Same premium, <span id='content-div-one-span'>2x</span> the value</h2>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Apply Now</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- content part two -->

        <div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-12' id="content-div-two">
                <h2><span>CARE COVER</span> PLAN</h2>
                <p>Ensures affordable, comprehensive cover</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>Coverage for family</li>
                    <li>Covers everything under a standard health policy</li>
                    <li>Sum Insured options upto 5lacs with deductibles</li>
                    <li>Sum Insured on family floater basis</li>
                    <li>Hospitalisation expenses + pre - post hospitalisation covered</li>
                    <li>All room/ICU/nursing/medicine/surgery etc charges covered</li>
                    <li>Day care procedures covered</li>
                    <li>Coverage available at all leading hospitals across the country</li>
                    <li>Deductible 50,000/100,000 options available. Deductible finances at 0% EMI</li>
                    <li>Tax benifits under section 80D</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- form -->

        <div>
            <div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12' id="form-div">
                <h2><span>GET</span> QUOTE</h2>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <div id="form">
                        <section id="form-section-one">
                            <p>Enter Your Name</p>
                            <input type="text" name="name">
                            <p>Your Mobile No.</p>
                            <input type="number" name="number">
                            <p>Email-Id</p>
                            <input type="email" name="email">
                        </section>
                        <section id="form-section-two">
                            <p>Gender</p>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value='female'><span>Female</span>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value='male'><span>Male</span>
                            <input type="radio" name="gender" value='others'><span>Others</span>
                            <p>Source of Income</p>
                            <select name="income-source" id="">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select One --</option>
                                <option value="">alpha</option>
                                <option value="">beta</option>
                                <option value="">gamma</option>
                            </select>
                            <p>Annual Income/Salary</p>
                            <input type="number" name="salary">
                        </section>
                        <section id="form-section-three">
                            <p>Our team will get in touch with you for further processing</p>
                            <p>Please select the number of family members you want to get insured with you</p>
                            <select name="family-memers" id="">
                                <option value="" selected disabled>-- Select One --</option>
                                <option value="">alpha</option>
                                <option value="">beta</option>
                                <option value="">gamma</option>
                            </select>
                            <p id='greeting-text'>Thank You</p>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" id='form-btn'>Next</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- video -->

        <!-- <div>
            <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-12' id="video-div">
                <video width="400" controls>
                    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>
            </div>
        </div> -->

        <!-- media mentions -->

        <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-12' id="media-mentions-div">
            <h2><span>MEDIA</span> MENTIONS</h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/2017.10.06_09-23-18bhaskar.png')); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" class="img-responsive"src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/vccircle.png')); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/TheHindu-Logo.png')); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/Zee-Business-CS6-1110x550.png')); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/dribbble_001_2x.png')); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/the-economic-times-logo-png-1.png')); ?>" >
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/yahoo-logo-png-transparent-background-768x256.png')); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo e(asset('/web/loancard/Media/yourstory.png')); ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- footer -->

        <div class="row" id='footer'>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 pull-left">
                <p>Copyright © {{ date('Y') }} LetsMD. All rights reserved  </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 pull-right">
                <p>
                    Get social with us 
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/LetsMDMedbay/" target="_blank">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-md">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4urUJpHcA9LpeRQ1O2hdjw" target="_blank">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-md">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/company/letsmd" target="_blank">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-md">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('web/js/medicalInsuranceScript.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

My CSS file :

```
#main-logo {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#transparent-div {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.7;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
#content-div-one {
    color: #E97C2B;
    background: #f1efef;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 300px;
}
#content-div-one button {
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #105e7b , #44b649);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px black;
    border: none;
    font-size: 170%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
#content-div-one button:hover {
    font-size: 175%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px black;
}
#content-div-one button:focus {
    outline:0;
}
.container-fluid {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
#banner-container {
    background-image: url('/images/family.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 500px !important;
    padding-top: 20%;
    position: relative;
}
#banner-text-div {
    color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 70% !important;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    bottom: 14%;
}
#banner-text-div h1 {
    font-size: 400%;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-style: italic;
}
#banner-text-div h2 {
    font-size: 340%
}
#content-div-one h2 {
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 5%;
}
#content-div-one-span {
    font-size: 300%;
}
#content-div-two h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #59A553;
    margin-top: 8%;
}
#content-div-two p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #306577;
    font-size: 150%;
    /*margin-bottom: 6%;*/
}
#content-div-two h2 span {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#content-div-two ul {
    color: #306577;
    font-size: 150%;
    margin: 5% 10%;
    line-height: 200%;
}
#form-div {
    background: #f1efef;
}
#form-div h2, #media-mentions-div h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #59A553;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#form-div h2 span, #media-mentions-div h2 span {
    font-weight: bolder;
}
#form {
    background: white;
    padding: 5%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px black;
    width: 50% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#form section p {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #306577;
    margin-top: 10%;
}
#form section select, #form section input[type='text'], #form section input[type='number'], #form section input[type='email'] {
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #306577;
    background: #f1efef;
    font-size: 175%;
    margin-bottom: 5%
}
#form section select {
    height: 45px !important;    
}
#form-btn {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5% 25%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #105e7b , #44b649);
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px black;
    border: none;
    font-size: 170% !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
#form-btn:hover {
    font-size: 175%;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px black;
}
#form section input[type='radio'] {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
#form-section-two span {
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: 120%;
}
#form-section-three p:first-child {
    color: #E97C2B;
}
#greeting-text {
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200% !important;
}
#media-mentions-div {
    margin-bottom: 8%;
}
#footer {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
}
```

My JS file :

```
var sectionNumber = 2;

function toggleForm() {
    if (sectionNumber === 0) {
        $('#form-section-one').css('display','block');
        $('#form-section-two').css('display','none');
        $('#form-section-three').css('display','none');
    }
    else if (sectionNumber === 1) {
        $('#form-section-one').css('display','none');
        $('#form-section-two').css('display','block');
        $('#form-section-three').css('display','none'); 
    }
    else if (sectionNumber === 2) {
        $('#form-section-one').css('display','none');
        $('#form-section-two').css('display','none');
        $('#form-section-three').css('display','block');
    }
    else {

    }
}

toggleForm();
```

What I expect (as stated) is that the footer should come at the bottom of the page and not overlap the elements above it.

What I expect :

[image]

What I'm getting :

[image]

Thank You

Comment: add a wrapper "row" for the content above the footer section and check

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, try validating it on https://validator.w3.org/ . A stray tag could cause this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Add a wrapper row for the content above footer section
[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70nmx1vs/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-12' 
    id="media-mentions-div"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.
Thanks !